# matplotlib savefig IO error

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to use the matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() function to save some figures.
I am saving them to a directory, however I keep getting the error:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(savepath,dpi=dpi,size=size)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 577, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1476, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt5agg.py", line 161, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2211, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 526, in print_png
    filename_or_obj = open(filename_or_obj, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Of course the file doesn't exist, as I am trying to save it now.
The directory does exist, I have checked repeatedly.

I am completely baffled, as this worked perfectly fine 2 days ago, but with no changes to the code it does not now.  EDIT: I updated the version of the anaconda python distribution that I was using before, From 32 bit anaconda 2.0 to 64 bit 2.3, both for python 2.7.

Does anyone have any clue?
Thank you for reading my desperate plea for assistance!

EDIT:
I am also getting what I believe to be the same error from saving txt files in  python now.

```
    f = open(fname, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\DropBox\\Dropbox\\abc\\Time resolved spectroscopy data\\LiHoF4\\High resolution 1cm\\power spectra\\Si\\RT\\25ns\\CUT POWER SPECTRUM LiHoF pumping 5G5 449.8nm DC si detector 1cm resolution 25ns data aquisition 2000 points 5AVG RT 450nmlongpassfilter.0.dpt_fitting_output.txt'
```

Could this be to do with the long filename?
I don't understand why there would be a problem with a file not existing when opening it to write to.

Comment: Egad.  Part the first - that filename is an affront to my eyes.  It surely can't hurt to shorten it.  Part the second - are you using Python 2, Python 3 ... did you switch?  I would start with trying using single `\` and putting an `r` in front of the string.  If those don't work, there's probably not much we can help with other than suggest double checking capitalization and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I shall try using raw strings.